# precommit: running a linter that only takes one filename at a time

Tags: pre-commit.com

We have a linter that runs with `xqlint lint target_file` but doesn't seem to support multiple filenames.

Is there a way in precommit to run against each file separately, without resorting to

`entry: bash -c "for $f in $@; do xqlint lint $f; done"`

(which seems to work but is ugly and less portable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is intentionally not.  starting and stopping processes repeatedly is slow and wasteful.  the tool should adjust to take multiple positional arguments

__

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit